# Navigation Controller и Modal Segue, передача данных

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigationcontroller

Здравствуйте. На схеме 3 экрана:

1. Данные которые необходимо отфильтровать
2. Отфильтрованные данные
3. Настройки фильтрации

Экран 3 открывается при нажатии на кнопку "Filter settings" через Modal Segue (экраны 1 и 2). 
Экран 2 открывается при нажатии кнопки "Filtered" (экран 1) через Show Segue.

При нажатии на "Cancel" (экран 3) вызывается функция dismiss, закрывая модальное окно, при этом возвращается тот экран с которого была нажата кнопка "Filter Settings", навигация между 
 1 -> 2 и 2 -> 1 работает как и должна.
Однако столкнулся с проблемой, как правильно реализовать открытие экрана 2 при нажатии на кнопку "GO TO FILTERED" с экрана 3, чтобы при этом передавались параметры для фильрации в управляющий класс экрана 2 и не сломалась навигация между  2 -> 1? Пробовал через разные Segue, но навигация тогда не работает.

[image: modal segue problem]

Comment: Предложу возвращаться на экран 1 без анимации, и оттуда переходить на 2 (предполагаю, что модель хранится где то отдельно, и к переходу отношения не имеет). Либо делать экран 3 частью стека (типа экран 1.5) и тогда, при надобности перейти с 1 на 2 просто добавлять в стэк 1.5 и 2 вместе

Comment: либо при нажатии go to filtered смотреть кто показывает модальный экран, и заменять его на экран 2, и уже после этого делать dismiss

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ,спасибо за комментарий, я рассматривал вариант с переходом к 1 экрану, а потом на 2... но подумал, что должно быть более изящное решение, т.к. только начал осваивать ios. Насчет использования стека, не совсем понял. Вы предлагаете убрать экран 3 и сделать его частью экрана 1? Вот вариант смотреть кто показывает экран мне больше нравится. Можете привести простой пример кода как это можно реализовать? или хотя бы какие функции использовать? Кто показывает это Presenter? Каким способом его можно изменить?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге решил данную проблему, используя Unwind Segue. Для этого добавил в классы экрана 1 и 2 функцию

```
@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

}
```

На экране 3 привязал кнопку "GO TO FILTERED" к prepareForUnwind через Unwind Segue. Данный способ позволяет автоматически определять с какого экрана(1 или 2) был открыт экран 3. Затем в классе экрана 1 реализовал код для перехода к экрану 2 сразу после выхода из экрана 3.

```
var fromFilterSettings = false

@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
   fromFilterSettings = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
if fromFilterSettings {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFiltered", sender: self)
     fromFilterSettings = false
   }
}
```